# Joomla 2.5 button "Show all topics from this category" in blog pagination

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

Hold standart page nav from Joomla 2.5 need to add one button "Show all topics from this category", but there is no any idea how to do that "trick".

How to? Use all my resources for searching in Google & other sites, there is no any answers

Will be glad for any help, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by topics ? Is it articles or keywords ?

Look for something like a module which displays all articles from one category: [displaynews](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/frontend-news/736) or anything like that will do the job.

If you are looking for a module which will display all the article linked to a same keyword : [FJ Related Articles Plus](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-display/articles-display/related-items/6195)

If then you want your topics to be displayed in an article, you have several plugins :

- [Modules Anywhere](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/6402)
- [Content - Load Module plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/How_do_you_put_a_module_inside_an_article?)
- [Load module into article plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/core-enhancements/coding-a-scripts-integration/embed-a-include/6958)